# Native dynamic-sized UI component for React Native

Tags: react-native

I want to build iOS react native component - analog of Text, where width and height is not known, but calculated dynamically depending from its content. As I see from debugging, RCTText.drawRect method is called with calculated rect already, but my component is called with empty rect if i did not define sizes via styles.

How to define needed rect for custom View?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in 'shadow' view concept. It looks like not documented, but React Native uses 'shadow' views to calculate layout before actual rendering. So RCTShadowText class is used for layout of  tag and its RCTMeasure function:

```
static css_dim_t RCTMeasure(void *context, float width)
{
  RCTShadowText *shadowText = (__bridge RCTShadowText *)context;
  NSTextStorage *textStorage = [shadowText buildTextStorageForWidth:width];
  NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = textStorage.layoutManagers.firstObject;
  NSTextContainer *textContainer = layoutManager.textContainers.firstObject;
  CGSize computedSize = [layoutManager usedRectForTextContainer:textContainer].size;

  css_dim_t result;
  result.dimensions[CSS_WIDTH] = RCTCeilPixelValue(computedSize.width);
  if (shadowText->_effectiveLetterSpacing < 0) {
    result.dimensions[CSS_WIDTH] -= shadowText->_effectiveLetterSpacing;
  }
  result.dimensions[CSS_HEIGHT] = RCTCeilPixelValue(computedSize.height);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more explicit about how you solved it? I have a native UI Component and I am not able to make RN calculate the frame correct: it's always zero unless I hardcode the width and height using the style in RN.

Comment: @Giuseppe You have to implement own RCTMeasure function

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `onLayout` property on the text view and see if it has more lines that you would like to have. So you would do the following:

1. use an initial width for the text item
2. wait for `onLayout` to fire and calculate how much width your text component would need based on the rendered dimensions
3. set the calculated width, causing a rerender with the calculated width

Comment: The component I have implemented is a native UIButton. The onLayout method you have mentioned is defined in the React Native side, and from ReactNative I don't know how to get the intrinsicContentSize of my custom view.

Comment: @Giuseppe sorry for the late response: the onLayout method gets the native layout information provided by the RN renderer / layouter to you: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.26/docs/view.html#onlayout

Comment: @DanielSchmidt looks like your approach works only for JS components, not iOS ones. Internally onLayout uses RCTMeasure function i've described bellow...

Comment: yes, my point is that you don't need to build a native component for this usecase