# Allowing a native iOS component to set its own height in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm wrapping an existing iOS component that expects to control its own height. So the component will modify its frame property but of course RN does its layout based on the style applied so ignores that. I'm looking for a nice way to allow the component to resize itself within the React Native layout.

I could override the setFrame method on and communicate the new height via an event back to the JS code then set the height style but it seems like there must be an easier way!

Any suggestions?

Comment: How aboud this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31852658/native-dynamic-sized-ui-component-for-react-native/32886095#32886095

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does seem like raising an event every time the height changes is the way to go. I'm doing that by subclassing the existing component and overriding setFrame and setReactFrame (which comes from the React UIKit category)

```
- (void) notifyNewHeight:(CGFloat) height {
    _currentHeight = height;
    NSDictionary *event =  @{
                             @"target": self.reactTag,
                             @"height": [NSNumber numberWithFloat: _currentHeight]
                             };
    [_eventDispatcher sendInputEventWithName:@"VENTokenFieldChangeHeight" body:event];
}

- (void) setReactTag:(NSNumber *)reactTag
{
    [super setReactTag:reactTag];
    [self notifyNewHeight:self.frame.size.height];
}

- (void) setFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if (frame.size.height != _currentHeight && self.reactTag != NULL) {
        [self notifyNewHeight:frame.size.height];
    }
    [super setFrame: frame];
}
```

You also need to define the event in the manager:

```
- (NSDictionary *)customDirectEventTypes
{
    return @{
             @"VENTokenFieldChangeHeight": @{
                     @"registrationName": @"onTokenFieldChangeHeight"
                     }
             };
}
```

It's not pretty, but it works.

As I've answered my own question I'll leave my answer un-accepted for the moment in case anyone has a better solution!